# iPhone X screen issue

Tags: iphone, display

I have an iPhone X that recently had the screen replaced but now when it charges up to 100% the screen doesn't turn on. I have figured out that by unplugging the connection cables and plugging them back in it fixes the issue. I don't think that the connecters are the issue though because they fit snuggly into their beds and they show no sign of damage. Could this be some sort of internal hardware issue or maybe it just needs a software update? Thoughts?

Comment: Doesn't your screen replacement have a warranty?

Comment: What difference would it make? This is the second screen that is doing this, thus why I think it is not the screen or the connections.